# Python split strings between " \" " into array of values

Tags: python, json, regex

Struggling a bit here, could use some expertise.

**Sample string:**

(Single string but multi-line code fenced here so it doesn't run off the screen)

`message_string = '{"Message": "Lab Test Type \"thing1 [Phase 1]\"` `requires the following additional Lab Test Types to be recorded` `when Passing: \"thing2 (ug/g) [Phase 1]\", \"thing3 (pass/fail` `[Phase 1]\", \"thing4 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]\", \"thing5` `(pass/fail) [Phase 1]\"."}'`

**Desired state:**

```
[
    "thing2 (ug/g) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing3 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing4 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing5 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]"
]
```

**Regex Tried:**

```
import re

split_message = re.split('\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\",', message_string)
```

**Results:**

```
[
    '{"Message": "Lab Test Type \"thing1 [Phase 1]\" requires the following additional Lab Test Types to be recorded when Passing: ',
    'thing2 (ug/g) [Phase 1]',
    ' ',
    'thing3 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]',
    ' ',
    "thing4 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]",
    ' ',
    "thing5 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]"."}'
]
```

**Questions:**

- How do I peel off the initial `{"Message...` element?, all the spaces (`' '`) and the last `."}` so that whats left is only an array with the `things`?

**EDIT 1:**

- I should have been clearer in the sample. `thing1, thing2, thingN` could be **any** string; in reality they are dissimilar words.
- @anubhava's solution got me the closest.
- Its unclear to me why I need to surround `message_string` with `r''' ... '''`. Will have to reasearch as I've not come across this syntax before in working with Python.
- I will likely need a negative lookahead to eliminate `thing1` from the results.

Comment: Don't use `split`. Use `re.findall(r'\\"(.*?)\\"', string)`

Comment: That sample string is JSON. Decode it, loop it, and then apply regex to your problem.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/wQgofX

Answer (score 0):

`re.findall` gets the job done nicely.

```py
import re

message_string = '{"Message": "Lab Test Type \"thing1 [Phase 1]\" requires the following additional Lab Test Types to be recorded when Passing: \"thing2 (ug/g) [Phase 1]\", \"thing3 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]\", \"thing4 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]\", \"thing5 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]\"."}'
result = re.findall('thing[0-9] \([a-z]*\/[a-z]*\) \[Phase [0-9]\]',message_string)  
print(result)
```

Out:

```
[
    "thing2 (ug/g) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing3 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing4 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]", 
    "thing5 (pass/fail) [Phase 1]"
]
```

Comment: It does not return all the values OP wants.

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer in the sample. `thing1, thing2, thingN` are in reality dissimilar words.

Answer (score 0):

why not trying these `re.findall("thing[^\[]*\([^\]]*\]", message_string)`

Comment: Again, would love to try it, but `thing` is not a common word in the real string. I provided a bad sample.